# Changing position.x causes skspritenode to not display

Tags: swift, ios8, sprite-kit

Hey everyone: i'm wondering if this is just an xcode bug, or if I'm just missing something really stupid. I have a game where the background scrolls by. Every update tick, I calculate the amount of time since the last update, multiply that by a constant and move the background by that amount.

Here's whats weird... The code snippet below, when run, causes bg1, bg2, fg1, and fg2 to NOT display in the scene.

```
func updatePos(timeSinceLast:CGFloat)
{
    bgSpeed = BG_TIME_SPEED*timeSinceLast
    fgSpeed = FG_TIME_SPEED*timeSinceLast

    //move both background nodes
    bg1.position.x -= bgSpeed
    bg2.position.x -= bgSpeed

    //move both foreground nodes 
    fg1.position.x -= fgSpeed;
    fg2.position.x -= fgSpeed;
```

This code snippet, when run, works just fine and everything displays:

```
func updatePos(timeSinceLast:CGFloat)
{
    bgSpeed = 3.97734984755516  // <--- I CHANGED TO A CONSTANT INSTEAD OF A CALCULATION
    fgSpeed = 3.97734984755516

    //move both background nodes
    bg1.position.x -= bgSpeed
    bg2.position.x -= bgSpeed

    //move both foreground nodes 
    fg1.position.x -= fgSpeed;
    fg2.position.x -= fgSpeed;
```

Please help me! I have absolutely NO CLUE what is going on. Thanks!

UPDATE: uliwitness, here are the printlns:

```
func updatePos(timeSinceLast:CGFloat)
{
    println("timeSinceLast: \(timeSinceLast)")
    println("BG_TIME_SPEED: \(BG_TIME_SPEED)")

    bgSpeed = BG_TIME_SPEED*timeSinceLast
    fgSpeed = FG_TIME_SPEED*timeSinceLast

    println("bgSpeed: \(bgSpeed)")

    bg1.position.x -= bgSpeed
    bg2.position.x -= bgSpeed

    fg1.position.x -= fgSpeed;
    fg2.position.x -= fgSpeed;
```

and heres the console output:

timeSinceLast: 0.0165845339652151

BG_TIME_SPEED: 120.0

bgSpeed: 1.99014407582581

UPDATE #2: Code that calls updatePos:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    timeSinceLastUpdate = currentTime - lastUpdateTime
    lastUpdateTime = currentTime
    backGroundNode.updatePos(CGFloat(timeSinceLastUpdate))
```

Comment: Have you tried printlning the values of timeSinceLast and BG_TIME_SPEED? What are they? How and where do you declare them? WHere do they get values assigned?

Comment: Added the console output to the post - see above. Thanks!

Comment: post the code that calls updatePos ... do you perhaps run it in a loop?

Comment: Yes, in the main gamescene's update function, i call updatePos getting an offset from the last update using the currentTime property of the update function. So, it returns a slightly different timeSinceLastUpdate every time.

Answer (score 0):

Arg! I figured it out. the very first run of update, the currentTime property of the update function is something like 50000 and the lastUpdateTime variable is initialized at 0.0. So, the foreground sprite is moved by 50,000 units the first frame. Thanks for all the responses though! Cocos2D's suggestion helped me find the issue.